# Как увидеть что выводит(в поток вывода) программа при запуске на mac os?

Tags: macos

Когда запускаешь программу она не запускается. 
Как понять почему это не произошло? Как увидеть вывод этой программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываете консоль(Finder> Applications> Utilities> Console), заходите во вкладку «Отчеты».
Чтобы просмотреть журналы сбоев и зависаний приложений, щелкните «Системные отчеты» для системных приложений или «Отчеты пользователей» для пользовательских приложений. Вы увидите множество журналов с расширениями файлов, такими как .crash, .diag и .spin. Щелкните их, чтобы просмотреть их в панели «Информация».